# How does this run command work ... “splunk:///”

Tags: windows

I am stuck at something that is probably simple to someone.  I am able to open run and type in `splunk:///`

And it fires:

```
"C:\program files\application\me.exe" /someswitch
```

What is the trick for making these?  I would like to make something along the lines of `myapp:///`

And fires:

```
"C:\program files\application2\mine.exe" /force
```

Comment: I figured out this is a URL .... how do I make one of my own

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389204/how-do-i-create-my-own-url-protocol-e-g-so

Answer (score 0):

It’s known as a “[Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) Scheme](https://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes/uri-schemes.xhtml)” and while you can technically hack settings in one system’s OS to allow a custom one to exist, that kind of defeats the purposes of the scheme.

The whole idea of a URI like `ftp://`, `http://` and such is that these are common schemes that are universally accepted and known to be useful to such a broad swath of users *that* is when a scheme is set and defined.

So you cannot just make one up—like `cooldude://`—and such and expect it to work as expected. Yeah, this could be useful on your system and the specific browser you are using. But what if you want to distribute that app to others? Are to you really going to insist that users change core settings in an OS or a browser and do so enough that somehow your app is popular yet somehow the IANA doesn’t recognize it as such? I wouldn’t hold my breath about something like that happening.

That said—as you have noticed—some OSes like Windows have custom URIs set in the OS. But again, it’s not a simple task to create such a thing or expect it to easily work anywhere past your own system’s environment.